# Hartl Rails Tutorial - Seed User Passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working my way through the excellent Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl, and I'm trying to wrap my head around an aspect of the seed users. I just finished chapter 9, so I've got a working login/logout/edit/delete system with admin privileges. As part of this chapter, we create some dummy users in the fixtures file:

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  admin: true
```

My question is: how do I login as michael@example.com? It's not clear to me what the password is. On a related note, what is the best practice for creating a universal "admin" user? Should I use a fixture, or should I add one to the database through the Rails console before deploying the app?

Thanks for your help!

---

Edit - here's the link to the BitBucket repository: https://bitbucket.org/jonathan_buck/sample_app/overview

Answer (score 4):

You're generating password digest from string "password"

```
User.digest('password')
```

So user's password is "password"

Comment: Thank you - very direct and to the point. What would you say if I told you this didn't work? I use michael@example.com as the user name and password as the password, but I'm unable to log in.

Comment: To answer that question you need to provide more information: code excerpt responsible for login functionality; validation errors, to be sure you have exactly "invalid email or password" error; test excerpt to be sure you've created user record before trying to login etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what the smoking gun could be, so I've posted the link to the git repository.

Answer (score 1):

The password is not saved as-is in the database. Instead a digest/secured version of the same is saved. The method #digest takes a parameter and outputs the digest version.

So, technically, the set password is "password". But in the database, you'll find it gibberish.

Makes sense?

Comment: Did this answer your question? Or, do you need some more clarity. 
Do mark the answer that helped you as BEST. It helps the others to easily find the solution. Cheers

Comment: The answer seems straightforward enough, but I'm unable to login using 'password' as the password. Hoping to figure this out before I check off a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what the smoking gun could be, so I've posted the link to the git repository.

Answer (score 0):

To address the main question what is database seed. db/seed.rb is a very nifty thing that helps you to seed some test users really fast. As you can see it has the .rb extension so it is a normal ruby program nothing unusual. You have access here to all your Models and don't have to enter everything manually from console. 
Well I guess what's the deal with password you already figured out form the previous answers. Just take a look at the method digest, and on [SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-i/) is the perfect article about how user should be authenticated.
And for your final question take a look at [this article](http://everydayrails.com/2012/07/31/rails-admin-panel-from-scratch.html), it will help you understand the concept